# exec basename not working from windows makefile

Tags: windows, makefile, build, gnu-make

I am working on a windows make file which has the below statement

```
Win10_SDK_Version := $(shell find $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include -maxdepth 1 -type d -path $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include/[0-9.]* -exec basename {}\; 2> output.txt | sort | tail -n 1)
```

However, I see the variable Win10_SDK_Version is not populated. To debug, I printed the variable $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK) just before this line and it is populated as expected

```
WROOT_WIN10_SDK=["E:/Myscpetre20/depot/sim/sim-20fq1/build/gobuild/compcache/cayman_msvc_desktop/ob-11144741/windows2016-clean/win/Program Files/Windows Kits/10"]
```

And the contents of the output.txt file says that the statement failed--`find: basename: No such file or directory`

If I shorten the above statement to below, excluding exec basename---

```
Win10_SDK_Version := $(shell find $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include -maxdepth 1 -type d -path $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include/[0-9.]* 2> output.txt | sort | tail -n 1)
```

The above statement executes fine so sure that this is some problem with the way I am using "-exec basename {}\;". I also tried to include single quotes for basename like below--

```
Win10_SDK_Version := $(shell find $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include -maxdepth 1 -type d -path $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include/[0-9.]* -exec 'basename {}'\; 2> output.txt | sort | tail -n 1)
```

But even that fails, can anyone guide me how to correctly include exec basename in the above statement?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should avoid using paths containing whitespace when dealing with make and makefiles.  It is very difficult to do so.

If the only place you need to use the `WROOT_WIN10_SDK` variable is inside of recipes and `shell` commands, then it can be done but you have to remember to quote that variable properly.

It will probably be simpler to write your command like this:

```
Win10_SDK_Version := $(shell (cd '$(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include' && ls -1 [0-9.]*) 2> output.txt | sort | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: I got your point, not to use paths containing whitespaces, but for legacy reasons I need to use this line. Basically wanted to know how to correct the exec basename part of my command.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that it's not the basename part of your command that's wrong.  The problem you're having is that because you haven't quoted the variable containing whitespace, the shell will parse it incorrectly.  You can run this command from a shell prompt (UNIX shell, not command.com) and get the same problem.  It's not related (in this instance) to make at all.  If you want to use paths with spaces in them with shell commands you MUST quote them.

Comment: Thanks understood now